# My python program ends after updating the return for a function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a simple game where either the user tries to guess the computer's number or the computer tries to guess the user's number. I can choose a game mode at the start and play through it but when I go back to the main menu and select another game mode the program just ends. I would like to know why it is ending and not playing through the other game mode.
Here is the code:

```
import random 

def show_start_screen():
    print("""
  ._________________________________.
  |                                 |
  |  ~ Welcome To Guess-A-Number ~  |
  |              PRESS              |
  |      ~  1      OR    2  ~       |                   
  |     You ^ Guess | PC ^ Guess    |
  |              PRESS              |
  |          4 To End Game          | 
  |_________________________________|""")
    is_playing_hg = False
    is_playing_cg = False
    selecting = True
    while selecting:
    game_mode = input("\n> 1, 2, OR 4: ")
    try:
        int(game_mode)
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a Number.")
    else:
        game_mode = int(game_mode)
        if game_mode == 1:
            is_playing_hg = True
            is_playing_cg = False
            selecting = False
        elif game_mode == 2:
            is_playing_cg = True
            is_playing_hg = False
            selecting = False
        elif game_mode == 4:
            is_playing_cg = False
            is_playing_hg = False  
            selecting = False
            show_credits()
    return is_playing_hg, is_playing_cg, selecting


def play_human_guess():
    game_finished = False
    while not game_finished:
        print("playing1...")
        game_finished = True
        

def play_computer_guess():
    game_finished = False
    while not game_finished:
        print("playing2...")
        game_finished = True


def show_credits():
  print("\nThanks For Playing!")


# Game starts running here
is_playing_hg, is_playing_cg, selecting = show_start_screen()

while is_playing_cg:
    #Start Game
    play_computer_guess()
    
    answer = input("""\nDo You Want to Play Again? (y/n): """)
    answer = answer.lower()
    if answer in ["n", "no"]:
      is_playing_cg = False
      is_playing_hg, is_playing_cg, selecting = show_start_screen()    

while is_playing_hg:
    #Start Game
    play_human_guess()
    
    answer = input("""\nDo You Want to Play Again? (y/n): """)
    if answer in ["n", "no"]:
      is_playing_hg = False
      is_playing_hg, is_playing_cg, selecting = show_start_screen()    

show_credits()
```

Comment: How are you writing the code? Does your IDE have a debugging and breakpoint feature? Are you able to create a [mcve]?

Comment: Note: while selecting: is not part of your start screen function and neither is the return, so those would throw errors if you've copied it here like that

Comment: sorry, those should be under the start screen function however it must have gotten reformated when I copied it over. I will edit that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your loop repeats if you select no, then pick the same mode

For example, if you start with mode 2

In `while is_playing_cg`, you enter no, then go to the selection screen, and enter 1 or 4, then `is_playing_cg= False`, so that while loop ends, and you never check that variable again.

If you start with mode 1, that first guess loop is never entered , but the same logic applies to the second loop when you do switch modes, and then both loops are done, and you then call the credits

I think your `while selecting` loop is misplaced because it'll always be False when it's returned from your start screen

Seems like you want something like so

```
while is_playing_cg or is_playing_hg:
    if is_playing_hg:
       ... 
    else:
      ... 

   is_playing_hg, is_playing_cg, selecting = show_start_screen()
show_credits()
```